# Newtonsoft.DeserializeObject for generic class

Tags: json, json.net

I have a JSON response like the following

```
{
    "msg": "1",
    "code": "2",
    "data": [
        {
            "a": "3",
            "b": "4"
        }
    ],
    "ts": "5"
}
```

I would like to create a generic class

```
public class DTWSResponse<T>
{
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public T data { get; set; }
    public long ts { get; set; }
}
```

so this class will map each of the variable. But the `data` portion can be generic, i.e. it might have different format rather than 2 variables `a` and `b`.

So I create another class

```
public class DTProf
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

and in my code, I call as

```
DTWSResponse<DTProf> prof = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTWSResponse<DTProf>>(json);
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'DataTransfer.DTProfile' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path 'data', line 1, position 40.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `"data"` is an array, but you are trying to map it to an `object` of type `T`. Try `public IList<T> data { get; set; }` instead...

Comment: use the correct type for the generic type argument `prof = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTWSResponse<IList<DTProf>>>(json);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the correct type for the generic type argument

the JSON shown has a collection for the `data` property. So use a collection as the type argument. No need to change the generic class.

```
var prof = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DTWSResponse<IList<DTProf>>>(json);
var a = prof.data[0].a;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. I would keep the `DTWSResponse` class the same as it is and use `List<DTProf>` as the data type.

Answer (score 2):

Make `data` a generic list and you should be fine...

```
public class DTWSResponse<T>
{
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public IList<T> data { get; set; }
    public long ts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is also a correct answer, however I can only accept one, so I'll upvote yours instead. Thanks.